# Keyboard suddenly using wrong layout, do not recall editing any configs

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input

Last night after restarting I found that my keyboard layout changed from the normal uk layout I use. I made some changes and it was back to normal, but whenever I restart it changes back again.

I have tried using `dconf-editor` and I have tried various other things to no avail. What caused the change and how do I remedy the situation?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> switched the keyboard input source. This solved my problem.